# Getting distance information on custom data table with Views (Drupal 7)

Tags: views, location

I am using Views to display a custom table (locations).  I have everything setup properly but now, I would like to get the distance from the current user to display.

I have first tried to get a custom field in there and do a pre_render to calculate the distance.  It works, but it makes it impossible to sort by distance since the data is modified after the fact.

I tried to figure out a way to add an expression Select to the Views query, but haven't found any ways to do so.  This would most likely be the best solution though.

I then tried to use Location module, but I can't figure out a way to make the Location: (proximity, distance...) fields appear in my fields list. Tried using the location handlers on my lat and long fields, but nothing different happens (ie: location_views_handler_field_latitude).

Anyone knows how to get this working with custom data?

The end goal:  Having the user enter is location, geocode it, then show their distance from the location's custom table (lat, long fields).

Comment: I used location module several times for this effect. You may just need a relationship in order to get the distance field working. It's been a while though so I can't say for sure. According to the documentation you must enable the location search sub module: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/location

Comment: I've been trying multiple options and I can't figure out how to get to my goal.  Nothing seems to be working.